# problema com evento dblclick

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

tenho um codigo que estava funcionando e de um dia para o outro parou de funcionar, não estou entendendo o porque disto !!

Não esta nem disparando o evento ...

segui o codigo abaixo:

```
<table style="width: auto;" id="tblEditavel" >
<thead>
   <tr>

      <th style=" text-align: center; width: 50px; ">Valor</th>

   </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

<tr>

    <td class="editavel" style="text-align: center; width: auto ; font-weight: bold;"> abc </td>


  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

o js vem aqui:

```
jQuery(function($) {


            $('#tblEditavel tbody tr td.editavel').dblclick(function(){
      //$('.editavel').dblclick(function(){

                if($('td > input').length > 0){ // verifica se já existe algum input já na <td>
                   return;
                }

          console.log('teste');

                var conteudoOriginal = $(this).text();
                var novoElemento = $("<input type='text' value='"+trim(conteudoOriginal)+"' class='campo_altera' />");      

                $(this).html(novoElemento.bind('blur keydown', function(e){

                var keyCode = e.which;
                var conteudoNovo = $(this).val();

                    if(keyCode == 13 && conteudoNovo != '' && conteudoNovo != conteudoOriginal){

                        var objeto = $(this);

                        $.ajax({
                            type:"POST",
                            url:"assets/php/alterar_vt.php",
                            data:{

                                valor_antigo:conteudoOriginal,
                                valor_novo:conteudoNovo

                            },
                            success:function(result){
                                objeto.parent().html(conteudoNovo);
                                $('body').append(result);
                            }
                        })


                    }else if( keyCode == 27 || e.type == 'blur')

                        $(this).parent().html(conteudoOriginal);
                }));

                $(this).children().select();

            });




        });
```

Comment: vc está utilizando qual navegador ? 
aperta f12 e vai em console e veja se está escrito algo e posta aqui

Comment: Utilizo o chrome amg, esta atualizado na ultima versão e o evento nao dispara ... verifique que eu coloquei um console.log() para ver se esta disparando o evento e nada aparece.

Answer (score 0):

O erro está na aplicação do método `.trim()` nesta linha:

```
var novoElemento = $("<input type='text' value='"+trim(conteudoOriginal)+"' class='campo_altera' />");
```

Altere para:

```
var novoElemento = $("<input type='text' value='"+conteudoOriginal.trim()+"' class='campo_altera' />");
```

> O método *trim* em JavaScript possui a seguinte sintaxe:

```
string.trim()
```

**[Documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)**

**Reprodução:**

```js
jQuery(function($) {


            $('#tblEditavel tbody tr td.editavel').dblclick(function(){
      //$('.editavel').dblclick(function(){

                if($('td > input').length > 0){ // verifica se já existe algum input já na <td>
                   return;
                }

          console.log('teste');

                var conteudoOriginal = $(this).text();
                var novoElemento = $("<input type='text' value='"+conteudoOriginal.trim()+"' class='campo_altera' />");      

                $(this).html(novoElemento.bind('blur keydown', function(e){

                var keyCode = e.which;
                var conteudoNovo = $(this).val();

                    if(keyCode == 13 && conteudoNovo != '' && conteudoNovo != conteudoOriginal){

                        var objeto = $(this);

                        $.ajax({
                            type:"POST",
                            url:"assets/php/alterar_vt.php",
                            data:{

                                valor_antigo:conteudoOriginal,
                                valor_novo:conteudoNovo

                            },
                            success:function(result){
                                objeto.parent().html(conteudoNovo);
                                $('body').append(result);
                            }
                        })


                    }else if( keyCode == 27 || e.type == 'blur')

                        $(this).parent().html(conteudoOriginal);
                }));

                $(this).children().select();

            });




        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width: auto;" id="tblEditavel" >
<thead>
   <tr>

      <th style=" text-align: center; width: 50px; ">Valor</th>

   </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

<tr>

    <td class="editavel" style="text-align: center; width: auto ; font-weight: bold;"> abc </td>


  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: fiz a alteração e não surtiu feito, nem o evento console.log() esta mostrando .... e sobre esta alteração, funcionava da forma que estava !!

Comment: Coloquei na resposta uma reprodução do código funcionando. Veja se está errado em algum lugar.

Comment: sim, eu vi que esta funcionando ,,,, porem na minha aplicação continua não dando resposta nenhuma ! ... o que pode ser, muito estranho isso

Comment: Bom, o único erro aparente que tinha no código era o `trim`. Fora isso tinha que analisar todo o código que não está na pergunta. Se quiser criar um JSFiddle com todo o código eu posso analisar pra vc.

Comment: ok amigo .... agora vou embora para casa descansar ..... amanha posto !!! Tenha uma otima noite e obrigado

Comment: realizei alguns teste e encontrei o motivo do erro na seguinte parte: 

if($('td > input').length > 0){ // verifica se já existe algum input já na <td>
                   return;
                }

Qual o problema nesta parte ?? pois funcionava e no jsfiddletbm funciona

Answer (score 0):

Veiriquei seu codigo vc está utilizando o trim de  forma errada a syntax é 
string.trim() e não trim(string)
Você pode ver funcionando aqui  https://jsfiddle.net/hq5omaop/4/

```
jQuery(function($) {


        $('#tblEditavel tbody tr td.editavel').dblclick(function(){
  //$('.editavel').dblclick(function(){
            if($('td > input').length > 0){ // verifica se já existe algum input já na <td>
               return;
            }

      console.log('teste');

            var conteudoOriginal = $(this).text();
            var novoElemento = $("<input type='text' value='"+conteudoOriginal.trim()+"' class='campo_altera' />");      

            $(this).html(novoElemento.bind('blur keydown', function(e){

            var keyCode = e.which;
            var conteudoNovo = $(this).val();

                if(keyCode == 13 && conteudoNovo != '' && conteudoNovo != conteudoOriginal){

                    var objeto = $(this);

                    $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        url:"assets/php/alterar_vt.php",
                        data:{

                            valor_antigo:conteudoOriginal,
                            valor_novo:conteudoNovo

                        },
                        success:function(result){
                            objeto.parent().html(conteudoNovo);
                            $('body').append(result);
                        }
                    })


                }else if( keyCode == 27 || e.type == 'blur')

                    $(this).parent().html(conteudoOriginal);
            }));

            $(this).children().select();

        });




    });
```